# How to pass user defined variable as argument to function/aggregate in Cassandra 3.0

Tags: function, cassandra, aggregate, cassandra-3.0

**Table/Type Structure:**

```
Create type typ_pks_details(
tpks_value Text,
tpks_date  Text,
tpks_comp_flg Text
);
Create Table pk_summary (
pks_nbr_key text,
pks_type_value text,
pks_type_character text,
pks_details map<text, frozen<typ_pks_details>>,
PRIMARY KEY (pks_nbr_key,pks_type_val)
);
```

**Function/Aggregate:**

```
Create FUNCTION sfunc_compute_value (state map<Text,Text>
               ,ps_type_val Text
               ,ps_type_char Text
               ,pm_pks_details map<text, frozen<typ_pks_details>>) 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS map<Text,Text>
LANGUAGE java
AS '
......<<Other code goes here>> 
//Clarification 2
//How to traverse typ_pks_details to fetch data

return state;';

Create AGGREGATE compute_value 
              (Text
               ,Text
               ,map<text, frozen<typ_attr_dtls>> 
             //Clarification 1 
             //How to pass map column pk_summary.pks_details map
              ) 

SFUNC sfunc_compute_value 
STYPE map<Text,Text>
INITCOND {}
;
```

**Query:**

```
Select compute_value(pks_type_value,pks_type_character,pks_details) As 
       Summary 
  From pk_summary
 Where pks_nbr_key='100' Allow Filtering;
```

**Question:**

Required to pass a user defined column (pks_details) (*Clarifcation 1 in above snipet*) in query to aggregate/function and compute the values (*Clarifcation 2 in above snipet*).
Please note the scenario is explained above and not the original tables are revealed.